# Jackson @JsonDeserialize not working on field

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

`@JsonDeserialize` not working on field.

Using Spring Boot 2.

Code:

```java
@Data
public class EventOddPOJO {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EventOddPartDeserializer.class)
    private String part;

    @JsonProperty("ss")
    private String score;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EventOddMinuteDeserializer.class)
    private String minute;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EventOddSecondDeserializer.class)
    private String second;

    @JsonProperty("over_od")
    private String overOd;

    @JsonProperty("home_od")
    private String homeOd;

    @JsonProperty("draw_od")
    private String drawOd;

    @JsonProperty("away_od")
    private String awayOd;

    @JsonProperty("under_od")
    private String underOd;

    @JsonProperty("time_str")
    private String timeStr;

    @JsonProperty("add_time")
    private String addTime;

    @JsonProperty("handicap")
    private String handicap;

    public static class EventOddPartDeserializer extends StdDeserializer < String > {

        public EventOddPartDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public EventOddPartDeserializer(Class < ? > vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

            String timeStr = p.getValueAsString("timeStr");

            if (Objects.isNull(timeStr)) {
                return "-";
            }

            return timeStr.split(" - ")[0];

        }
    }

    public static class EventOddMinuteDeserializer extends StdDeserializer < String > {

        public EventOddMinuteDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public EventOddMinuteDeserializer(Class < ? > vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

            String timeStr = p.getValueAsString("timeStr");

            if (Objects.isNull(timeStr)) {
                return "-";
            }

            return timeStr.split(" - ")[1].split(":")[0];

        }
    }

    public static class EventOddSecondDeserializer extends StdDeserializer < String > {

        public EventOddSecondDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public EventOddSecondDeserializer(Class < ? > vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

            String timeStr = p.getValueAsString("timeStr");

            if (Objects.isNull(timeStr)) {
                return "-";
            }

            return timeStr.split(" - ")[1].split(":")[1];

        }
    }

}
```

Json:

```
{
                    "id": "35008186",
                    "home_od": "1.952",
                    "handicap": "+3.5",
                    "away_od": "1.740",
                    "ss": "95:98",
                    "time_str": "4 - 04:08",
                    "add_time": "1603807890"
}
```

Comment: Did you get any error message? Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: @flaxel My debugger break point is not working inside `deserialize` method. Any errors.

Comment: I'm not even sure how this will compile, public EventOddPartDeserializer(Class << ? > vc)

Comment: Please include the JSON that you are trying to deserialize

Comment: @lane.maxwell attached JSON

Comment: @lane.maxwell its complied successfully. And runed

Comment: I'm not sure how, the code you've posted has invalid syntax, namely all the constructor arguments that contain `Class << ? > vc`

Comment: @lane.maxwell its just in example. Its doesn't exists in code

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example as outlined here: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be far easier to obtain assistance if we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use 3 different deserialisers at the same time for the same value in `JSON` payload. If you need to parse value into 3 different properties you can create new `POJO` and implement parsing in custom deserialiser.

`POJO`-s:

```
@Data
class EventOddPOJO {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("ss")
    private String score;

    @JsonProperty("over_od")
    private String overOd;

    @JsonProperty("home_od")
    private String homeOd;

    @JsonProperty("draw_od")
    private String drawOd;

    @JsonProperty("away_od")
    private String awayOd;

    @JsonProperty("under_od")
    private String underOd;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EventOddPartDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("time_str")
    private EventOddPart timeStr;

    @JsonProperty("add_time")
    private String addTime;

    @JsonProperty("handicap")
    private String handicap;
}

@Data
class EventOddPart {
    private String part;
    private String minute;
    private String second;
}
```

Custom deserialiser:

```
class EventOddPartDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<EventOddPart> {

    @Override
    public EventOddPart deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException{
        String timeStr = p.getValueAsString();

        EventOddPart eop = new EventOddPart();
        if (Objects.isNull(timeStr)) {
            return eop;
        }
        String[] parts = timeStr.split(" - ");
        String[] minSecs = parts[1].split(":");
        eop.setPart(parts[0]);
        eop.setMinute(minSecs[0]);
        eop.setSecond(minSecs[1]);

        return eop;
    }
}
```